# How use BEM correctly with Sass

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

I'm starting to use BEM methodology [BLOCK, ELEMENT, MODIFIER] and I have doubts about it.

Inside a section called 'participate', I have a form, so:

```
<section class="participate">
  <form class="participate__form">
    <label for="name" class="participate__form__label"></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="participate__form__input"/>

  </form>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.participate {
 &__form {
   // css here
 }
 &__form__label {
   // css here
 }
 &__form__input {
   // css here
 }
}
```

The class is too large inside the form, so told me that the right would be go one level deep:

```
<section class="participate">
  <form class="participate__form form">
    <label for="name" class="form__label"></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="form__input"/>

  </form>
</section>
```

But how should I style this?

I'm using it like this:

```
.participate {
 .form {
   // CSS HERE
   &__label {
   // CSS HERE
   }
   &__input {
   // CSS HERE
   }
 }
}
```

But I really believe this is not the right approach. Please, can someone give me a light here?

Comment: What makes you feel uncomfortable about this approach?

Comment: the necessity of use dot to target classes.. i was looking for BEM + Sass and the dev's that are using never use dot to target classes, so my code appears to be wrong in some way... @Alohci

Comment: "I don't know what to name my stuff" is not a real problem.

Comment: great comment cimmanon. thanks!

Comment: @cimmanon I disagree, knowing what to name things is one of the biggest problem in programming. However, this question is primarily opinion-based and not a problem that fits on SO.

Comment: @cimmanon - not knowing how to name things well is a very real problem for programmers, I'm minded of a day wasted thinking 'on-order' meant reserved for a customer when it meant ordered from a supplier but not received, if the developer responsible had come here to ask how to name things maybe I wouldn't have wasted that Saturday!

Comment: @StephanMuller I disagree too. BEM itself denies css-selectors with nested elemens (in BEM terminology), so it's literally definitely NOT opinion-based question.

Comment: the answers to this question are very useful to understanding BEM. @cinnamon's statement that not knowing how to name stuff is not a real problem is so far off the mark that its laughable. Whilst there clearly is not a single 'correct' answer to this question, that does not mean that the question does not have significant value. I understand why it has been closed and still I think that closing it was a mistake.

Comment: @StephanMuller why is this opinion based? BEM is really strict in what it considers correct and what considers incorrect. There are a few correct ways of doing it, but this is true for any question. As long as there is a clear right and a clear wrong, as with BEM, then it is not an opinion based question.

Answer (score 6):

At first, you don't need cascade `.participate .form`. Better to use mix: `.participate__form` + `.form` on the same DOM-node.

`participate__form__label` is also wrong usage of BEM-methodology. Use `participate__form-label`, or `participate-form__label`, or just `form__label`.

I'd do it like that:

```
<section class="participate">
  <form class="participate__form form">
    <label for="name" class="form__label"></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="form__input"/>
  </form>
</section>
```

Styles for `participate` block and `__form` element:

```
.participate {
  &__form {
    // outer styles here
  }
}
```

And styles for `form` itself

```
.form {
  &__label {
    // inner styles here for label
  }
  &__input {
    // and input customization
  }
}
```

If you still need customization for your form in `participation` context you can use modifiers:

```
.form--god-bless-participation {
  .form__label {
    // label customization
  }
}
```

In that way you're free to use your form whenever you need, and also you can replace your original form in `participate` block with another one, or even with `form`-like block.

Answer (score 1):

```
<section class="participate">
  <form class="participate__form">
    <label for="name" class="participate__form__label"></label>
```

In the above your are using `participate` twice, one time for the holder / parent class and the second time as an prefix for your form.

When using `participate` as an parent class, you do not need the prefix:

**html:**

```
<section class="participate">
  <form class="form">
    <label for="name" class="form__label"></label>
```

**sccs:**

```
.participate {
     form {
        &__label {
        }
     }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
<section>
  <form class="participate__form">
    <label for="name" class="participate__form__label"></label>
```

**sccs:**

```
.participate {
     &__form {
        &__label {
        }
     }
}
```

But when `participate` is your block, your HTML can according to http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/bem.html, look like that shown below:

```
<section class="participate">
  <form class="participate__form">
    <label for="name" class="participate__input participate__input--label"></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="participate__input participate__input--text"/>
  </form>
</section>
```

And your SCSS:

```
.participate {
    &__form {}
    &__input {
        &--label {
        }
        &--text {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `--label` syntax indicates modifiers, not elements. In my opinon `--label` and `--text` aren't modifiers of one element, they are different elements. I think your last example is not in line with the BEM convention.

Comment: @StephanMuller thanks for your comment. Do you have an example for the label which meets BEM in your opinion?

Comment: Personally I'd use `.participate`, `.participate__form` and `.participate__label`. This indicates that the label is indeed a child of the `.participate` class, but gives a bit more freedom in how deep in the DOM you put it. While it would generally also be a child of `form`, I don't think it's necessary to indicate the exact structure in all classes.

Comment: @StephanMuller thanks. indeed that should work

Comment: Looking at the example you linked, I think `--text` might be a valid modifier though, as you could have similar `__input` elements of different variations, like `--number` or `--file`.

Comment: Personally I would take a more flexible approach. Along the lines of what @Alex suggests, I think it's better practice to treat `form` as a block rather than an element. Especially when you consider that there may be other forms on the site. I would advise styling generic forms first, and then use 'participate' as a modifier: `.form--participate`. This would leave you with much cleaner code: http://sassmeister.com/gist/487fbee21edceb11f7e9